# Fastest/Best way to send data from a python script to a Processing.js script, while serial is already in use?

Tags: python, data-transfer, processing.js

I have data that is sent from a microcontroller to a python neural network over serial to process, where then, its output needs to be sent to a Processing.js script to visualize.

**My question is** what is the best way to do this?

MCU - serial -> Python - ? -> Processing.js

from what I found, I can use websockets, or is it possible to utilize two serial ports at the same time and send the output of the neural network over another port to Processing.js?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.  "What is the best way?" is simply a wrapper around "give me code/design to solve this problem" -- which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: No it’s not. That’s not what I’m asking. I’m asking if someone can inform me of different modes of data transmission that may help me out with this problem. I’m not asking for any code or how-to’s. Just resources. @Prune

Comment: As stated in the intro tour's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), asking for off-site resources is *specifically* off-topic on this site.

Comment: Please be aware that I discontinued and archived Processing.js back in December of 2018. So this question is mostly about "how do you get data from Python to the browser", to which the counter-question is: "depends: at what point does the user load your Pjs code?"

Comment: Also, if this is new code: stop using Processing.js immediately and start using [P5.js](https://p5js.org/) instead =)